# Flex: Trigger event in skin container

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to perform an action (make an element in the skin container visible or not) based on an event that takes place in the container of the skinned element.
-CardArea(Group)
--SkinnedInput(TextInput)
---InputSkin

So I have a mouse over event in `CardArea` and I want an element in the `InputSkin` to show or not based on the mouse position. How could I do that?

Comment: Toggle the visibility property of the component you want to hide. Based on the limit information you have provided; I'm not sure it is possible to get more detailed than that.

Comment: Do you do need hide/show a component based on x/y coordinates over `CardArea`? or..Do you do need  hide/show a component when you pass mouse over another component? Please see this **[LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108036807/ExMouseOver_01.swf)**, Is this what you want?